# implicit declaration in parsing rule warning

Tags: antlrworks

again I am still confused with this rule

```
block
    :  '{'
       (variable   |    stat)* 
       (    LINE_COMMENT 
       |    COMMENT
       |    WS
       )*
       '}'
    ;
```

I got same warning, where the lexer rule is

```
WS
    :   (' ' | '\r'|'\t'|'\u000C'|'\n') -> skip 
    ;

COMMENT
    :   '/*' .*? '*/' -> skip 
    ;

LINE_COMMENT
    :   '//' ~('\n'|'\r')* '\r'? '\n' -> skip 
    ;
```

Answer (score 0):

The `skip` command in your lexer rules tells ANTLR to not actually produce tokens from those rules. ANTLR recognizes the presence of this command and suppresses the creation of those token types altogether, which is why you're seeing the warning when trying to reference them from a parser rule.

- If you want the parser to handle whitespace and comment tokens, then remove `-> skip` from your lexer rules.
- If you want the lexer to prevent whitespace and comment tokens from reaching the parser, then remove the references to `WS`, `COMMENT`, and `LINE_COMMENT` from any parser rules and leave the lexer rules as-is.